# How can I change the table header color and text color?

Tags: html, css

At first the example looked easy to be changed because the author commented throughout the code, but now I'm stuck, I can't change the color of the header and the color of the header text.

```css
/*the following HTML and body rule sets are required only if using a % width or height*/
/*html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}*/
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto; /*if you want a fixed width, set it here, else set to auto*/
  min-width: 100%; /*if you want a % width, set it here, else set to 0*/
  height: 100%; /*set table height here; can be fixed value or %*/
  min-height: 100%/*104px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows + caption + thead*/
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0; /*need enough padding to make room for caption*/
  text-align: left;
}
.scrollingtable * {box-sizing: border-box;}
.scrollingtable > div {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid white; /*The header's border-top*/
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px; /*this determines column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: #9BC2E6; /*header row background color | header color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div {
  min-height: 0/*43px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows*/
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll/*auto*/; /*set to auto if using fixed or % width; else scroll*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #9BC2E6; /*border around table body*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {background: white;} /*match page background color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: -20px; /*inverse of column header height*/
  /*margin-right: 17px;*/ /*uncomment if using % width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; /*inverse of caption height*/
  margin-top: -1px; /*inverse of border-width*/
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {padding: 0;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px; /*header cell padding*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > :first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  border-left: 1px solid #9BC2E6; /*leftmost header border*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  color: white; /*header row font color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:after {content: attr(label);}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-left: 2px solid white; /*borders between header cells*/
}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead {float: right;}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: -1px; /*inverse border-width*/
  background: white; /*match page background color | Right corner*/ 
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white; /*Can become an issue if handled badly*/
  top: -1px; /*inverse of border width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr {background: white;} /*White lines*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white; /*Horizontal lines*/
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody:last-of-type > tr:last-child > * {border-bottom: none;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: #DDEBF7;} /*alternate row color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * + * {border-left: 2px solid white;} /*borders between body cells AKA columns*/
```

```html
<!--[if lte IE 9]><style>.scrollingtable > div > div > table {margin-right: 17px;}</style><![endif]-->
<div class="scrollingtable">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <caption>Central de Controle da Engenharia</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><div class="header_title" label="Column 1"></div></th>
            <th><div class="header_title" label="Column 2"></div></th>
            <th><div class="header_title" label="Column 3"></div></th>
            <th>
              <!--more versatile way of doing column label; requires 2 identical copies of label-->
              <div><div>Column 4</div><div>Column 4</div></div>
            </th>
            <th class="scrollbarhead"/> <!--ALWAYS ADD THIS EXTRA CELL AT END OF HEADER ROW-->
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    Faux bottom caption
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a declaration that sets the header background color:

```
.scrollingtable > div:before {
   top: 0;
   background: #9BC2E6; /*header row background color | header color*/
}
```

You can simply change it to another HEX color, e.g. `#00ff00`

**EDIT**

To change the color of the text, see this declaration:

```
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   color: white; /*header row font color*/
}
```

change the `color` attribute to e.g. `#000`

Comment: I'm really sorry, I forgot to say I wanna change the color of the text :),

Comment: Worked! :) Thank you, for spending your time to help me!